# Magento 2 Frontend Thumbs up Vote

Tags: magento2, frontend

Does anyone know how to create upvote and downvote on frontend?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYt6E.png  like this one.

Comment: for products or overall website ?

Comment: for reviews only.

Answer (score -1):

I was have same issue,I have used below extension

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner/tree/magento2

use command for removing unused product images:

eav:media:remove-unused -> Remove unused product images.